# Why getJdbcTemplate().query returns null list after upgrading mySql?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbctemplate

I have recently upgraded from Java 6 to 8, mySql 5.5 to 5.7 and Spring MVC 2 to 5.0.9. I have following code, which worked before upgrade. But now if i try it returns list of Map with one entry, but Map is blank. But the truth is, database has one value available.

```
Map<Integer, String> transmittalIds =  new HashMap<Integer, String>();    
String query = "";
    query.append("SELECT TRANSMITTALID, TRANSMITTALCODE FROM LEADERTRANSMITTAL WHERE ")
            .append(" CASENUMBERREPORT = 'N'")
            .append(" AND STATUS = 'SENT'");

    List<Map<Integer, String>> list = getJdbcTemplate().query(query.toString(), new TransmittalIdMapper()); 

    public static final class TransmittalIdMapper implements RowMapper<Map<Integer, String>>{

            @Override
            public Map<Integer, String> mapRow(ResultSet rs, int arg1) throws SQLException {

                Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

                while(rs.next()){
                    int transmittalId = rs.getInt("TRANSMITTALID");
                    String transmittalCode = rs.getString("TRANSMITTALCODE");

                    map.put(transmittalId, transmittalCode);
                }
                return map;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("List size: "+list.size());

          if( list != null && !list.isEmpty()){
              System.out.println("List: "+list.get(0));
              System.out.println("Map: "+list.get(0).size());
              transmittalIds = list.get(0);
          }
```

Following is output:
**List size: 1**
**List: {}**
**Map: 0**

Comment: Did you try that query directly in the mysql client or some other SQL client? If it doesn't work there then it's most likely not a JDBC issue.

Comment: Btw, `while(rs.next())` inside `mapRow` seems odd - wouldn't that map multiple rows? If that code does what I think it does your list should never contain more than one map.

Comment: @Thomas I tried it in MySQL Workbench and it is returning one result. Yes, it would contain one entry and It has one entry, but that entry is Map of int and String and it is blank instead of values.

Comment: If there is 1 row only the `rs.next` will move to the next one, leading to an empty result. You shouldn't do `rs.next` in a `RowMapper` as the `JdbcTemplate` handles that for you. With this solution you would basically always skip the first row. So in short remove the while loop. This will return a list of maps with each map having 1 entry.